# cant update into the all column

Tags: c#, sql-server

The c# code:

```
protected void check_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection c;
    string str = "Data Source =(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;";
    str += "AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\DinoData.mdf;";
    str += "Integrated Security= True";
    c = new SqlConnection(str);
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        Session["tit"] = (string)title.Text;
        Session["Discrip"] = (string)Discrip.Text;
        Session["Doname"] = (string)Dinoname.Text;
        Session["wage"] = (string)wage.Text;
        Session["lo"] = (string)ddlcountry.SelectedItem.Text;
        Session["val"] = (bool)true;
        Response.Redirect("Had Manger.aspx", true);
        SqlCommand zer = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [User] SET did4 = 0", c);
        c.Open();
        zer.ExecuteNonQuery();
        c.Close();
    }
}
```

there is not an error but it is not updating
plss help
ok i update ehis is all the function

Comment: have you tried to run this command from a client e.g Management Studio and see what happens?

Comment: A note: your query is going to update every record to set `did4` to the value `0` without a limiting `WHERE` clause. Also, if you could, try to include more code. If you step through your application, does it get to the `zer.ExecuteNonQuery();` line? Perhaps you aren't even getting to that point due to a conditional statement somewhere? Another thing to look at, is your connection pointing to the correct database server and schema?

Comment: i want to update all the column no i did not  tried Management Studio i dont have this software and its get to the line

Comment: If you can, for context, provide more of the surrounding code. Could it be that you have a `try/catch` block around it somewhere, either directly or further up in a calling routine, that could be catching the exception and swallowing it?

Comment: no... it very simple code

Comment: Yes, however, if you are running it and it is not behaving they way you want, then there is a problem somewhere. We need to see what else you are doing before we can try to determine where a problem is actually occurring.

Comment: look at the updeate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Response.Redirect("Had Manger.aspx", true);` before you even hit your query execute. Comment that line out or move it to the end and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect("Had Manger.aspx", true);

Comment: Are you answering to yourself with a duplicate account?